# Java - Date as long value: how does TimeZone relate?

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, timezone

Could someone please explain in detail the following:

I have a `long` value which represents a `date`.

1. What will be the `timezone` associated with the `long` value?
2. How to convert the `long` value to a date with proper `time zone`?
3. Is there is way to identify the `timezone` associated with the `long date` value?

Comment: Check out [the API docs for java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) for an explanation. There might also be something in the Java Tutorials, but I haven't looked.

Answer (score 7):

The long is milliseconds since Jan 1970, GMT.  So, to that respect, it is GMT.

Answer (score 4):

A Date (either as a long or a [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)) represents a moment in time.

There is no TimeZone involved unless you're dealing with a Calendar.

You can create a Calendar for a given TimeZone and Locale like this:

```
long rightNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
Locale exampleLocale = Locale.GERMANY;
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST");

Calendar theCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(zone, exampleLocale);
theCaledar.setTime(new Date(rightNow));
```

Answer (score 4):

The `long` value which represents the `java.util.Date` is the number of milliseconds elapsed from epoch. (Jan 1, 1970)

```
/**
 * Allocates a <code>Date</code> object and initializes it to 
 * represent the specified number of milliseconds since the 
 * standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 
 * 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. 
 *
 * @param   date   the milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.
 * @see     java.lang.System#currentTimeMillis()
 */
public Date(long date) {
    fastTime = date;
}
```

- What will be the timezone associated with the long value?
  Can you attach a unit to a long value.? No.
  This is akin to saying given an int 2 what does it represent? . It could be 2 miles or 2 pounds.
- How to convert the long value to a date with proper time zone?
  You can't because of above.
- Is there is way to identify the timezone associated with the long date value?
  Nope.

Answer (score 2):

When time is in long format, `TimeZone` won't be associated with it.

You need to use either `SimpleDateFormat` (or) `Calendar` API to apply Timezone for long value.