# Getting Timezone Information from Long value in java

Tags: java

Can we get from which timezone the Long Value is produced? 
I have long values of Date. I want to know from which timezone it is generated.

For e.g

**Long value**: 1435640400000
**Date**: 30 June 2015 CDT

I want to develop program which input will be the Date in long value

that will return output as **Timezone** with the respective

long value for 30 June 2015 12:00 AM GMT/UTC

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - Date as long value: how does TimeZone relate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775047/java-date-as-long-value-how-does-timezone-relate)

Comment: Without further information such a value can be interpreted as any timezone. Typically (i would say) it's calculated as GMT.

Comment: As ceekay says, unless you interpret as GMT, there's no information to decide what Timezone this date / long cooresponds to

Comment: Normally long values are calculated as the `number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT`

Comment: @Dragondraikk I want corresponding GMT associated with Long Value. Duplicate question relate to the Locale, Calendar instance

Answer (score 2):

The unix time (as it is called) is not a date. You can calculate a date from it but it really is just the duration of seconds (or ms) since 01/01/1970 at 00:00 UTC.

This means it has no timezone attached to it. You need the "target" timezone to calculate the actual date from it, but simply having this number does not include any timezone information (which means you'll need to get it somewhere else in order to calculate dates).

Think of the unix timestamp more as a duration than a date. It's like saying "I'll meet you in 30 minutes". Those 30 minutes do not have a timezone attached to them. To you and the person you're talking to, that meeting might happen at different dates (e.g. 2:30pm vs. 3:30pm) because of timezones. But it will still happen at the same point in time relative to the moment you said it.

I hope this makes the difference somewhat clearer.

Answer (score -2):

There was a way to do this directly via the `getTimezoneOffset()` function in the `Date` class but that has been **deprecated**.

It has been replaced by

```
(Calendar.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) + Calendar.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET)) / (60 * 1000)
```

Comment: And deprecated with good reason. This method makes the assumption of a default timezone, as @mhlz's answer indicates.  Going via the Calendar class, as per the deprecation notice expects or assumes a timezone in the Calendar.  Thus, the time is interpreted as relative to a timezone.  It does not allow the inference of a timezone from a `Long`, as the OP requested.